# Help with epistemology homework related to film Shutter Island

Tags: epistemology

I am really sorry to ask this but I need some help regarding the philosophical interpretation of the movie Shutter Island. Hope someone can help me!

I need to analyze how does Teddy Daniels know who Andrew Laeddis is in reality? Is it trough rationalism, empiricism or criticism? I see elements of the three theories but I can't reach a conclusion!

Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps it is through all three of them. It is hard to tell what kind of answer you are expecting. Perhaps you could give us some samples of your own analyses (with specific examples of what "know in reality" means) to clarify.

Comment: What I have to analyze is how Teddy Daniels ends up knowing that he really is Andrew Laeddis, during the whole movie he thinks he is a federal marshal but it is at the end when he realizes that everything was a deception and that he is in reality the murderer, however, as you comment, the three theories could fit, what costs me a little is to determine if he realizes his true identity using rationalist reason, experiences and the sensory world of empiricism or if it is a combination of these two with criticism. I hope you can help me, I appreciate your response

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, so I can not help you specifically. But it seems to me that one would have to combine rational, empirical, and critical considerations in any event. Is there a particular need to single out one of them? Can't you just describe what you already see: how each of the three elements is used in the process? Then there is no conclusion to reach.

Comment: Indeed, I need to select one of the three theories and defend why it is the correct theory, with counterargumentation amd refutations on the other two theories. Thank you, you ve been really helpful